# can collections.deque be extended to build a "file buffer"?

Tags: python, deque

I want to build a circular file buffer, in python, to hold file names (strings). The buffer should have the following properties.

- The size of the buffer is the sum of the sizes of the files whose names are stored in the buffer. The buffer will have a maximum permitted size.
- When a new file is added, if the buffer size is less than the maximum permitted size, that file name string is added. Else, the oldest modified file is pushed out and the new one is added. If the newly added file is older than all the files already present in the buffer, nothing takes place.

Is it possible to extend deque for such a purpose?

Or should I write it from scratch? Is there any design ideas that I can use for this purpose?

thanks

suresh

Comment: A deque does have a `maxlen` property, which automatically discards objects from the other end of the queue.

Comment: Are you planning on modifying these files during the lifespan of this list (i.e. the 'oldest modified file' could become the 'newest modified file')?

Also, when you add a file that is 'older than all the files already present in the buffer', does it decrease the number of files in the queue or simply ignore the file?

Comment: Do you mean the max size should depend on the _length_ of the filenames? The _number_ of filenames? The _size_ of the files the filenames refer to?

Comment: @Darthfett I am planning to modify these files during the lifespan. Yea, the oldest can become the newest. When a file which is older than  all the files already, I dont want any action to take place. Hope I clarified it.

Comment: @agf the length of the filename has no role here. The size is the size of the files, the filenames referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I believe that Raymond Hettinger's interpretation of your question is correct, and your comment has clarified that you're not concerned with the length of the queue, but rather with the sum of all the filesizes. That makes a lot more sense, and I'm glad I finally understand what you mean. With that in mind, here's a simple implementation based on `heapq` that I believe satisfies all your stated requirements. Use it by `put`ting `(timestamp, filename, filesize)` tuples on the queue, and note that when you `get` an item from the queue, it will be the oldest file (i.e. the file with the smallest timestamp.)

```
import heapq

class FilenameQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, times_sizes_names, maxsize):
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self.size = sum(s for t, s, n in times_sizes_names)
        self.files = list(times_sizes_names)
        heapq.heapify(self.files)
        while self.size > self.maxsize:
            self.get()
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)
    def put(self, time_size_name):
        self.size += time_size_name[1]
        if self.size < self.maxsize:
            heapq.heappush(self.files, time_size_name)
        else:
            time_size_name = heapq.heappushpop(self.files, time_size_name)
            self.size -= time_size_name[1]
    def get(self):
        time_size_name = heapq.heappop(self.files)
        self.size -= time_size_name[1]
        return time_size_name
```

I added a `__len__` method so that you can test the queue before getting from it. Here's a usage example:

```
>>> f = FilenameQueue(((22, 33, 'f1'), (44, 55, 'f2'), (33, 22, 'f3')), 150)
>>> while f:
...     f.get()
... 
(22, 33, 'f1')
(33, 22, 'f3')
(44, 55, 'f2')
>>> f = FilenameQueue(((22, 33, 'f1'), (44, 55, 'f2'), (33, 22, 'f3')), 150)
>>> f.put((55, 66, 'f4'))
>>> while f:
...     f.get()
... 
(33, 22, 'f3')
(44, 55, 'f2')
(55, 66, 'f4')
```

See my edit history for a completely different solution involving `Queue.PriorityQueue` that is suboptimal. I forgot that `maxsize` enforces the limit by *blocking*, not by discarding elements. That's not so useful!

Comment: Except he wants it to have a `maxlen` in terms of the the sum of their lengths, not number of filenames, so you'd have to implement it manually. And you'll end up with O(n) removals because the `deque` won't be sorted by priority. You definitely need some kind of queue for this.

Comment: @agf, I'm assuming he was mistaken to want the `maxlen` to be the sum of the filenames' lengths. I can't imagine what the point of that would be. And your second point is the reason I mentioned `PriorityQueue`s.

Comment: Nice edit. You're right, that really doesn't make sense. My new guess -- he meant the size of the _files_ referred to by the filenames.

Comment: @agf, thanks. And I'm starting to realize that I misread "oldest" in the original question -- he didn't mean "first in," did he? Your comment makes more sense to me now...

Comment: Unless someone needs locks for a multi-threaded program, *heapq* is better than *Queue.PriorityQueue*.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger, you're right, and my justification for using `PriorityQueue` in spite of that was based on an erroneous assumption. Thanks.

Comment: +1 on this answer.  It is clean and easily modified to do whatever the OP actually intended.

Comment: @senderle Thanks for the solution. Could you please explain why PriorityQueue based solution is sub optimal? Or how does one compare heapq with PriorityQueue?

Comment: The problem with `PriorityQueue` is that it doesn't automatically discard anything. Instead, when full, it refuses to accept new entries. This will cause the main thread to "block" -- to stop running -- until one of the entries is removed by another thread. A normal, single-threaded program will hang at that point, since there _is_ no other thread. You could still use it, but you'd have to hand-code the discarding behavior, so PriorityQueue provides no advantage over the basic `heapq` module. Plus `heapq` is probably faster, since it doesn't have to worry about thread safety.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want a sequence of filenames for files up to a given maximum size.  If new files get added that exceed the maximum, you want to forget the oldest.

This simple deque based class should take care of it nicely:

```
from collections import deque

class FileDeque(object):
    'FIFO queue of files upto a given total size'

    def __init__(self, maxsize):
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self.d = deque()
        self.sizes = dict()
        self.currsize = 0

    def append(self, filename, filesize):
        'Add a new file to the FileDeque'
        self.d.append(filename)
        self.sizes[filename] = filesize
        self.currsize += filesize
        while self.currsize > self.maxsize and self.d:
            oldfilename = self.d.popleft()
            oldfilesize = self.sizes.pop(oldfilename)
            self.currsize -= oldfilesize

    def __iter__(self):
        'List files oldest to newest'
        return iter(self.d)
```

A sample session looks like this:

```
>>> f = FileDeque(maxsize=10000)
>>> f.append('raptors.txt', 2500)
>>> f.append('rexes.txt', 4200)
>>> list(f)
['raptors.txt', 'rexes.txt']
>>> f.append('stegos.txt', 5000)
>>> list(f)
['rexes.txt', 'stegos.txt']
>>> f.append('brontos.txt', 500)
>>> list(f)
['rexes.txt', 'stegos.txt', 'brontos.txt']
>>> f.append('dactyls.txt', 4000)
>>> list(f)
['stegos.txt', 'brontos.txt', 'dactyls.txt']
```

Comment: Except I don't think he wants FIFO, he wants min priority on last modified time.